# How to speeding up Python script to update columns in existing SQL table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Orders table in SQL that contains StoreOrderNumber, State and Country. State and Country are empty columns and i have to populate them based on the dataframe below:

```
data = {
    'StoreOrderNumber': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010],
    'State': ['CA', 'NY', 'TX', 'IL', 'FL', 'PA', 'OH', 'GA', 'MI', 'NC'],
    'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA']
}
```

The python code i have been using is:

```
# Addin data to Orders table
sn_conn = DatabaseConnection(config_file)
sn_conn.sqldb(env = env)
for each in tqdm(orders_final.StoreOrderNumber):
    state= orders_final.loc[orders_final.StoreOrderNumber == each, 'State'].values[0]
    country = orders_final.loc[orders_final.StoreOrderNumber == each, 'Country'].values[0]
    sn_conn.engine.execute(f"""UPDATE Orders SET State = '{state}' WHERE StoreOrderNumber = '{each}' """)
    sn_conn.engine.execute(f"""UPDATE Orders SET Country = '{country}' WHERE StoreOrderNumber = '{each}' """)
sn_conn.close()
```

While this works it is extremely slow. It performs about 7 update per second.
Is there any way I could modify this script so i can improve the speed of updating State and Country inside SQL Orders table using the python?

Comment: 7/sec is horrendous and suggests `StoreOrderNumber` isn't indexed. You can use only one UPDATE to modify multiple columns too. The fast way though is to store the data into a temporary/staging table and then perform an UPDATE on the target table, eg UPDATE target SET ...  FROM target INNER JOIN staging on target.ID=staging.ID`.

Comment: what's your DB engine?

Comment: There are other issues with this code too. It searches for the same rows multiple times. You could use [df.itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) instead, to iterate over the rows and read the fields you want from each row by name. Finally, string interpolation exposes you to SQL injection bus. Use proper parameters instead.

Comment: To start with, one UPDATE statement to set both values at once should speed things up.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest -  I am using SQLALchemy create_engine